# IOS: set alpha in a UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, alpha

I have an UIImage and I want to set its alpha at 0.00 after 3 seconds... In my UIImage there is a picture that I want to immediately see when I go in a view, but after 3 second it must disappear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy as that using core animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

if you dont want to slowly fade within 3 seconds, you can use

```
[UIView setAnimationDelay:3];
```

and reduce the animation duraction to 0.5f or something.
i think using a short fade out time feels better than just simply set hide to YES

Answer (score 5):

This will make it fade out within three seconds.  Call from viewDidLoad:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{myImage.alpha = 0; }];
```

Or if you want the animation to start at 2.5 seconds and last half a second, you could put that into a method (changing 3.0 to 0.5) and then call:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideMyImage) userInfo:nil repeats:no];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you showing your `UIImage` in a `UIImageView`?

If so, just set the `hidden` property on that image view to YES and the image view (with its image) will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove the sub-child view from the parent.

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

you can always add it later with

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```